# The original state of using Angular.js to validate form input

Tags: javascript, validation, angularjs

the code below is part of signin.html. when i visit that page, nick and password is surely empty, so the `myForm.nick.$error.required` is `true`. the error message is displayed. What i want is, when i visited the page, there's no error message on the page. What should i do? Thanks

```
<form ng-submit="signin()" name="myForm">
  <input type="text" name="nick" ng-model="data.nick" required>
  <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.nick.$error.required">Required</span><br>
  <input type="password" name="password" ng-model="data.password" required>
  <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.password.$error.required">Required</span><br>
</form>
```

Comment: When do you want the "Required" text to show up?  Is it on submit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a $dirty condition to prevent the required field message being displayed at  the beginning of page.

```
myForm.nick.$error.required && myForm.nick.$dirty
myForm.password.$error.required && myForm.password.$dirty
```

$dirty===true means that user has already interacted with the form.

Here is a [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KGd8K/1/)

Hope this helpful.